# Undefined variable in the view

Tags: php, laravel, view

I'm facing a problem with undefined variable in the view error. I've already looked for a solution but none really helped or made me figured out what it's going wrong..

I've already done the data passing to a view from a controller without problem. That's why I'm not really getting why this is not working. I'm trying here to have an access to a specific `theme` based on the link the user may have clicked

Here is the Controller code where I pass the `$themeDetailed` variable to the view

```
/**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $themeDetailed = Theme::findOrFail($id);
        return view('accueil', ['themeDetailed' => $themeDetailed]);
    }
```

The `accueil` blade view code

```
                        <!-- single course -->
                    @foreach ($themes as $thematique)
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="course">
                                <a href=" {{ route('themes.show', $themeDetailed->id)}} " class="course-img">
                                    <img src="main/assets/img/course01.jpg" alt="">
                                    <i class="course-link-icon fa fa-link"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a class="course-title" href="#">{{$thematique->intitule }} </a>
                                <div class="course-details">
                                    <span class="course-category">{{$thematique->categorie }}</span>
                                    <span class="course-price course-free">{{$thematique->filiereDesiree }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                        <!-- /single course -->
```

The routes

```
        | GET|HEAD  | themes              |                | App\Http\Controllers\ThemeController@index            | web,auth     |
        | POST      | themes              | themes.store   | App\Http\Controllers\ThemeController@store            | web          |
        | GET|HEAD  | themes/create       | themes.create  | App\Http\Controllers\ThemeController@create           | web          |
        | GET|HEAD  | themes/{theme}      | themes.show    | App\Http\Controllers\ThemeController@show             | web          |
        | PUT|PATCH | themes/{theme}      | themes.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ThemeController@update           | web          |
        | DELETE    | themes/{theme}      | themes.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ThemeController@destroy          | web          |
        | GET|HEAD  | themes/{theme}/edit | themes.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\ThemeController@edit             | web          |
```

So here is the link in the blade view supposed to get via the controller the specific theme :

```
<a href=" {{ route('themes.show', $themeDetailed->id)}} " class="course-img">
<img src="main/assets/img/course01.jpg" alt="">
<i class="course-link-icon fa fa-link"></i>
</a>
```

The themeDetailed variable is defined in the controller and passed to the view. I don't really understand why I still get it as an undefined variable
Should I define differently the routes, the link ? Is there something I'm missing there..? Thanks to help

Answer (score 0):

Where `$themes` comes from ? Maybe the Undefined variable is `$themes`
Make sure that you passed it to your `accueil` view.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer.. Sorry I didn't mention the variable.. It's the ```$themeDetailed``` instead which brings the undefined variable message error. I've defined the ```$themes``` one in another controller with the same logic.. and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$id` and put `$theme` in your controller method. Although I don't think this is the problem. Your view clearly is not what it should be. You pass a single record/collection to the view but in your view code there is a loop that doesn't fit.

And what is undefined? Which variable?

Comment: My bad, I edited the question. It's the ```$themeDetailed``` which is reported to be undefined

Comment: For the loop, it is another variable I'm using. I'm passing the ```$themes``` variable to the view via another controller and I loop through the results and show it in the view. Here is the code in this controller to do so: ```class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function accueil(){
     
        $themes = Theme::inRandomOrder()->take(8)->get();
        return view('accueil', ['themes' => $themes]);
    }
} ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing two variables to the view using two controller functions and that is not possible as when you call page route only one of the two functions will be called first and the other wont so that the controller function of the route will not run and the variable will be Undefined

You can simply send your two variables to the view via one function:

```
public function accueil($id)
{ 
    $themes = Theme::inRandomOrder()->take(8)->get(); 
    $themeDetailed = Theme::findOrFail($id);

    return view('accueil', ['themes' => $themes , 'themeDetailed' => $themeDetailed]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. Actually, I changed the controller : I'm using the ThemeController index function now to retrieve 8 themes to the ```accueil``` view in random order as the code means it. I tried then your proposition. I'm getting this error : ```Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ThemeController::index(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected```

Comment: And for what's about two variables to the view using two controller functions I didn't really understand.. What about the resource controller then and its different functions and variables ..?

Comment: You have two variables within the view ````$themes```` and ````$themeDetailed```` You are trying two send one variable in index function which is ````$themes```` but the other variable is not defined in index function or in the view